# Why Backblaze does not backup iTunes sync data?

Tags: iphone, backup, itunes

I am an iPhone user and am using Backblaze to backup my files on my PC.  iTunes stores iPhone sync data to `c:\Documents and Settings\(My Name)\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\(hex value)`.  There are normally thousands of .mddata and .mdinfo files and 3 plist files.

Recently, When I did an iPhone system restore, something went wrong.  The iTunes screwed up my application data and a wrong state got sync'd back to the iPhone.  The old iPhone apps' data are lost on both of the iPhone and the iTunes. So I immediately went to Backblaze web site to restore the iTunes sync data files.  Then I am shocked!  I don't see the mddata and mdinfo files in the backup! I can only see the 3 plist files there!

Here is the file type exclusion list where mddata and mdinfo are not on it:

wab~,vmc,vhd,vo1,vo2,vsv,vud,vmdk,vmsn,vmsd,nvram,vmx,vmem,iso,dmg,sys,cab,exe,msi,dll,dl_,wim,ost,o,log,ts

What's wrong?  Is Backblaze an online backup provider I should trust?

Answer (score 3):

I am the support agent from Backblaze.

I recently asked about this and I have found, that originally this was the case, however, the code that caused this behavior has been removed since before march of 2010.

So we will backup the sync data.

Comment: January 2014, http://www.backblaze.com/remote-backup-everything.html: "Backblaze also excludes podcasts in iTunes."